# How to find beginswith word in a string using NSPredicate?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, nspredicate

I am searching for a solution on how to format NSPredicate to search correct word in a string of text.
Currently I am using this code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"(content CONTAINS[c] %@)", word];
```

but it returns wrong resuls if the word is short, for example:
if the word is 'ail' it will return all strings with words which include this 3 letters.. But I don't need such abstract search, so how to search words 'beginswith' my word in a string?

Comment: It's often advisable to also search diacritic-insensitive. This is done with `CONTAINS[cd]`; adding `d`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Simply use `BEGINSWITH` instead of `CONTAINS`.

**Edit**

If you need to search in every word of a string, there is a technique which was presented in one of the talks in WWDC 2010. The basic idea is to create a separate entity `Word` which contains a single word and a reference of the containing object (the entity you're searching). You then do the search on the `Word` entity and return the objects which are related to the found words.

The query would then look something like this (provided you have a many-to-one relationship between your entity and `Word`: "ANY words BEGINSWITH[c] %@"

This would mean that you have to setup the words when creating your objects though.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I am speaking about a string, not a word. If I will use beginswith it will return all strings which begins with my word, but I need to return strings which contains words, begins with my word...

Comment: So what you need is something like "any word in content begins with XX"?

Comment: Yes, something like this. But it should return whole string. The thing is I need to find in ny Core Data recipes with one of ingredients by recipe title. For example if I search apple I need to find recipes with title 'Fuji Apples Tarte Tatin'.

Comment: I edited my answer to give you an example on how you could do it. This is from a WWDC 2010 Core Data talk, so if you're a registered developer you can have a look at the videos.

Comment: @Azia I would recommend using "CONTAINS" in that case

Comment: It is strange for me, but if I use just "content beginswith[c] %@" - it also works correct. So your first answer was also correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

search first with `BEGINSWITH` for "Foo", this will find you the beginnings of a string

```
"Foo Word1 Word2", "Foo OtherWord1 OtherWord2" (will find 2)
```

and than `CONTAINS` for " Foo" (note the space before Foo), which will give you words that starts with "Foo" presided with a space

```
"Word1 Foo Word", "Some OtherWord FooWord", "Misc    FooXWord" (will find 3)
```

Predicate :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"(content BEGINSWITH[c] %@) OR (content CONTAINS[c] %@)", word, [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", word]];
```

Comment: That's what i want ..
vary smart answer...Thanks dude

Answer (score 7):

If your text contains some punctuation chars between words you may use this predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"(name BEGINSWITH[c] %@) OR (name MATCHES[c] %@)", 
                              query,
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*[^\\w]%@.*", query]];
```

Comment: Wow! I thought tokenising was the only solution till I saw this.

Comment: This is easier and probably better than the accepted answer.

Comment: the regexp is quite slow, better to search for a regular string prefixed with space

Comment: `[^\\w]` can be replaced with `\\b`. `BEGINSWITH` part is redundant here at all + Injecting request input as-is inside of search pattern is not very wise. You at least should escape regex symbols first with use of [`escapedPatternForString:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1408386-escapedpatternforstring?language=objc)

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same issue and at first i thought your answers could help me, but they didn't. This one helped me, so...Take a look:

```
NSString *matchString =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @".*\\b%@.*",searchText];
NSString *predicateString = @"keyword MATCHES[c] %@";
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: predicateString, matchString];
```

Comment: Wow, this works amazingly well. Some of my words are between `( )`, e.g. `Hello (world)`, and your solution matches with `searchText == "w"`. Thanks.

If you have time, please explain how this works, I'm not familiar with `\b`.

Comment: Injecting request input as-is inside of search pattern is not very wise. You at least should escape regex symbols first with use of [`escapedPatternForString:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1408386-escapedpatternforstring?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

Try using compound:

```
NSCompoundPredicate *bPredicate =  [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"content BEGINSWITH[cd] %@",_SearchBar.text], [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"content CONTAINS[cd] %@", _SearchBar.text]]];
```